# How to output the result on different cell? (VBA Excel 2007)

Tags: excel, vba

I have calculated some values and there should be two results. I want to display these result in two different cell.

When I have changed A1 or A2 value, excel is stopped. Is there anyway I can display the values?

```
Sheet1 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Call DisplayResult 
End Sub

Module1 
Sub DisplayResult() 
     Range("A3").Value = Range("A1").Select.Value + Range("A2").Select.Value     
     Range("B3").Value = Range("B1").Select.Value + Range("B2").Select.Value 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use .select at all here -

Worksheet Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Sheet1.Range("A1:B2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Hello"
End If

End Sub
```

Module Code:

```
Sub DisplayResult()

Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value + Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
Sheet1.Range("B3").Value = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value + Sheet1.Range("B2").Value

End Sub
```

If you put the `Call DisplayResult` line in your Worksheet_Change sub routine without limiting what range it should be triggered on, then it will end up going into an infinite loop (DisplayResult triggers the Worksheet_Change sub). When should the DisplayResult code be triggered? Only when you have changed Range A1:B2 ?

Comment: Yep, Display Result will be triggered only when A1:B2 are changed.

Comment: OK I've added the Worksheet code - now it'll only trigger the event when A1:B2 are changed.